# Client application is not registered as a resource server

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, quarkus

I set up KeyCloak on my Quarkus application. Realm is 'quarkus', as is the client. I successfully get token from KeyCloak, but when I'm about to use it in whatever method on my service, I get this:

```
Caused by: org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: Unexpected response from server: 403 / Forbidden / Response from server: {"error":"invalid_clientId","error_description":"Client application [quarkus] is not registered as a resource server."}
```

application.properties is set like this:

> quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/realms/quarkus
> quarkus.oidc.client-id=quarkus
> quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=dFvRiItg9NjUA56h4nk4xPG4IqKFNPkG
> quarkus.oidc.tls.verification=none
> quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.paths=/*
> quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.policy=authenticated

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This error is returned from Keycloak when `quarkus-keycloak-authorization` is trying to get a policy decision from it. I think something is not set up correctly in Keycloak. Please see how it is configured in the Quarkus test: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/main/integration-tests/keycloak-authorization and review Keycloak docs: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html and also check Keycloak forums. Also, do you need Keycloak make an authorization decision ? I don't see any related config so may be you only need `quarkus-oidc` to have tokens verified ?

Answer (score 3):

Just go to the Keycloak console. Go to `Clients` tab and select your client. Then, turn on this option:
[image]

Do not forget to save the configuration. This should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while trying to set up keycloak in quarkus dev environment.

I found out there was a problem with the resource configuration. First I fixed a part of the problem by setting to true the `Authorization Enabled` setting in the client setting page.

It gave me another error: `invalid_scope, Requires uma_protection scope`
I'm guessing it's a client scope to add. I found a issue stating that it should be a scope and not a client scope but can't find it anymore.

anyway, the easiest way I found to fix this configuration for my dev environment was to reimport the quarkus realm from this file: [quarkus-realm.json](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/5cef5e856d8bd53afc1d611a64a48444f462e3b7/security-keycloak-authorization-quickstart/config/quarkus-realm.json)

it seems to be up to date and working. Next you can check the config to find out your missing params.